# Logic APP SSL connection error with MySQL db

Tags: mysql, azure, ssl, connection, database-connection

I got an issue with setting up the MySQL connection in Logic App. The database is in Azure as well.
I got an on-premise data gateway and it is working. SSL connection on MySQL db is "on" and the Azure service connection is "on" as well.
Any idea?

**Error**
[image: Error]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not screenshot your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Azure in Connection and security Set the Enforce SSL Connection to disabled. It doesn't matter what is the Cli or the Workbench Show.